# redirect stderr of ls

Tags: linux, unix, redirect, ls

I'm trying to redirect ls command's errors. But I found my redirection is wrong. For example, if I wrote this ls commands,

```
$ ls ;;;
```

Terminal says,

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
```

But, my redirected file wrote this,

```
ls: cannot access ;;;: No such file or directory
```

How can I catch differences between redirected file and terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the ;;; in quotes, bash will then always pass that argument to the ls command. Without quotes bash is trying to parse the ;;;, hence the error.

```
ls ';;;' 2> stderr.txt
< no output >

cat stderr.txt
ls: ;;;: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't think about that way.
however, I actually hoped to modify my redirected file